# When shall I enable constraints for sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I've got the point you have to use the `onConfigure()` callback to enable database constraints `db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);`. But those are available from API 16 only. My min SDK version is 14 so where shall I enable constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For lower Android levels - i.e. `Android 2.2` onwards that supports `SQLITE 3.6.22` use

```
@Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onOpen(db);
    if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
        // Enable foreign key constraints
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
    }
}
```

and add the key to your DB's directly

```
foreign_id INTEGER REFERENCES foreignparent [ON DELETE CASCADE]
```

Foreign key constraints are available only after SQLITE 3.6.19

Source: http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

> This document describes the support for SQL foreign key constraints
>   introduced in SQLite version 3.6.19